# discord.py Ping Command

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have problem with my discord.py command. I want to make ping command which will respond with my bot's ping. My code is below.

```py
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong :ping_pong:! Bot latency: **{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms**"
```

I also tried to write my code like this.

```py
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong :ping_pong:! Bot latency: **{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms**"
```

None of the above code works.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work. Does it print an error? If so, then send the error, and you're also missing the closing `)` in both the code blocks. Is that a copy paste error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this command and I've tested it to know it works.. you can try it:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'My ping is** {round(bot.latency*1000)} Ms**')
```

Btw, if you have defined bot as client, make sure to change bot.latency to client.latency

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a bracket to the end?

```
@bot.command() # set this to your bots variable
async def ping(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f"Ping!\nLatency is **{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms**!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you forgot the ) between ms** and ".

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong :ping_pong:! Bot latency: **{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms**")
```

This is the code fixed, if you want to use @client, just use this:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong :ping_pong:! Bot latency: **{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms**")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
embed = discord.Embed(
    title=" Pong!",
    description=f"The bot latency is {round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}ms.",
    color=0x42F56C
)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.